# Segue not performing on quick action when app is already open (Xcode 9)

Tags: ios, swift, ios11

**The Problem**

I wanted to create a quick action (3D Touch) that allows a user to go directly to the statistics section of a game. I based my solution on the code from [this](https://www.appcoda.com/3d-touch-tutorial/) tutorial and got it working with this code. I added some extra code because I want to use the quick action to do something different than in the tutorial. This is the function that is responsible for performing a segue from the initial view to the statistics view. It's in AppDelegate.swift:

**From AppDelegate.swift**

```
func handleQuickAction(shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem) -> Bool {

    var quickActionHandled = false
    let type = shortcutItem.type.components(separatedBy: ".").last
    if let shortcutType = Shortcut.init(rawValue: type!) {
        switch shortcutType {
        case .statistics:
            quickActionHandled = true

            // I use dispatchQueue to ensure that the segue occurs immediately
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self.window?.rootViewController?.performSegue(withIdentifier:     "ARView_to_stats", sender: self.window?.rootViewController)
            }

        }
    }

    return quickActionHandled
}
```

This function is called from the following delegate function:

**From AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(handleQuickAction(shortcutItem: shortcutItem))
}
```

This setup works perfectly if the app has been closed (from the app switcher / multitasking view) and I tap on the quick action. However, if I go home without closing the application completely and try to do the same, it does not go to the statistics view but rather to the game view.

I've tried this many times over and it crashes once in a while with the following message:

*com.apple.CoreMotion.MotionThread (11): EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x48307beb8)*

How could I change this to make it work as desired.

**What I tried**

- Removing DispatchQueue.main.async

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
var isQuickLaunched = false
var quickLaunchOption: Shortcut!

func handleQuickAction(shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem) -> Bool {
    var quickActionHandled = false
    let type = shortcutItem.type.components(separatedBy: ".").last
    if let shortcutType = Shortcut.init(rawValue: type!) {
        isQuickLaunched = true
        quickLaunchOption = shortcutType
        quickActionHandled = true
    }

    return quickActionHandled
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(handleQuickAction(shortcutItem: shortcutItem))
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    if (isQuickLaunched == true) {
        isQuickLaunched = false
        switch quickLaunchOption {
        case .statistics:
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self.window?.rootViewController?.performSegue(withIdentifier:     "ARView_to_stats", sender: self.window?.rootViewController)
            }
        }
    }
}
```